# Serpent Vulnerabilities, Migrate to Solidity?

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, dapps, serpent

With recent high profile bugs discovered in the core Serpent Language, would it be wise to henceforth make Solidity the deFacto Dapp Language?

https://medium.com/@AugurProject/serpent-compiler-vulnerability-rep-solidity-migration-5d91e4ae90dd

Answer (score 1):

Solidity is already the de-facto DApp language: Serpent is deprecated, and neither Viper nor Bamboo are mature enough for widespread use. Nearly all DApp projects are using Soldity.

This may change as and when these new projects mature, however.